# Missing BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission but compile/target SDK are configured to 30

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-ble

I'm implementing an Android library which supports some BLE utilities. In my build.gradle, both compile and target SDK are configured to 30, but I encountered missing permission error at compile time:

> Error: Missing permissions required by BluetoothDevice.getName: android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT [MissingPermission]

My understanding is that BLUETOOTH_CONNECT is available after SDK 31. Any idea why I can see this error even if I've forced the SDK to 30?

Comment: `Android library which supports some BLE utilities` - Maybe this  library has compile sdk set to 31.

Comment: Same problem here, which occurred after i updated AndroidStudio to Bumblebee